# Posts automáticos do Facebook perderam imagens

Tags: html, facebook

Olá.
Eu uso a API do Twitter para postar vagas do meu site automaticamente por lá, veja:
https://twitter.com/carreirafashion
[image: Vagas corretas no twitter]
As vagas ficam certinhas, com o título da vaga, descrição e uma imagem com o logo da empresa ao lado.

Nas configurações do Twitter, esta programado para enviar esses mesmos posts diretamente para o Facebook, o que acontece corretamente. Mas os posts enviados, de uma hora para outra (a partir de 13/02/2018), passaram a não exibir mais a imagem ao lado do post, veja:
https://www.facebook.com/carreirafashion
[image: Antes do dia 13]
[image: Depois do dia 13]

Antes as imagens apareciam normalmente, e do nada parou de aparecer. A Meta tag parece corretamente configurada, assim:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/site/_imagens/redes_logo.png" />
```

O que será que aconteceu? Se eu copio a URL de uma página e posto manualmente no Facebook (https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/vaga-de-moda/vaga/163591), a imagem aparece. Apenas esses posts enviados diretamente pelo Twitter que estão sem imagens. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A sua imagem vêm de um protocolo https acrescente o meta abaixo testei pelo  mesmo processo que você usa e deu certo:

Utilize o **og:image:secure_url** quando a **url** vem do um protocolo https.

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/site/_imagens/redes_logo.png" />
```

As dicas de utilização do Open Graph no facebook:

Ficar atento nas resoluções;

> Use imagens com pelo menos 1200 x 630 pixels para a melhor exibição em
>   dispositivos de alta resolução. No mínimo, você deve usar imagens que
>   tenham 600 x 315 pixels para exibir publicações na página com link com
>   imagens maiores. O tamanho máximo das imagens é de 8 MB

Atento ao tamanho mínimo de imagem;

> O tamanho mínimo de imagem é de 200 x 200 pixels. Se você tentar usar
>   uma imagem menor do que isso, você verá um erro no Depurador de
>   compartilhamento.

Atento ao uso dos atributos **og:image:width** e **og:image:height**

> O uso dessas marcações especificará as dimensões da imagem para o
>   rastreador para que ele possa renderizá-la imediatamente sem ter que
>   baixá-la e processá-la de maneira assíncrona.

Utilize a tag `<meta>` com atriguto **og:image:width** , **og:image:height**, troque og:image por **og:image:url**, se tiver utilizando https utilize **og:image:secure_url**;

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="187756311833261" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Carreira Fashion" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Comprador(a)" /> 
<meta  property="og:url" content="https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/vaga-de-moda/compradora/163591"/> 
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/site/_imagens/redes_logo.png" /> 
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.carreirafashion.com.br/site/_imagens/redes_logo.png"/> 
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="315" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Empresa de confec&#xe7;&#xe3;o admite profissional para atuar com compras de tecidos e aviamentos.Necess&#xe1;rio experi&#xea;ncia na &#xe1;rea de compras para confec&#xe7;&#xe3;o.Local: Mogi das Cruzes / SP." />
```

Você pode testar no Debug do facebook, abaixo:

**Ferramenta para depuração do Open Graph.**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

**Referência para Post Open Graph**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/

Comment: Obrigado. Vou tentar colocar a largura e altura pra ver se algo mudo. Sobre a ferramenta de depuração do Facebook, eu já havia testado e lá aparece a imagem certinha, assim como quando posta a URL manualmente no facebook. A imagem só não aparece nos posts automáticos do Twitter. Vou aguardar para ver se a altura e largura mudam algo na situação e aviso por aqui o resultado...

Comment: Não funcionou :( continua sem a imagem.

Comment: @RenanHoffmann alterei a resposta têm a ver com meta quando a imagem usa o protocolo https tem que usar o atributo og:image:secure_url